# Asynchronous connect() with one function call, using C++11 lambdas and Boost.Asio

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, boost

I've wanted to write a C++11 class for making IPv4 TCP connections and figured that it *probably* could be done with just one static function using some shared_ptr and lambda "magic". The following code *seems* to work - but I'm not entirely sure that it's safe and completely bug-free:

```
void Client::connect(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,
                     const std::string& address,
                     const std::string& port,
                     const Callbacks& callbacks)
{
  using namespace boost::asio::ip;

  std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket = std::make_shared<tcp::socket>(io_service);
  std::shared_ptr<tcp::resolver> resolver = std::make_shared<tcp::resolver>(io_service);
  tcp::resolver::query query(address, port);

  auto connectHandler = [socket, callbacks]
                        (const boost::system::error_code& errorCode, const tcp::resolver::iterator& it)
  {
    if (errorCode) {
      callbacks.onConnectionError("Could not connect: " + errorCode.message());
    } else if (it == tcp::resolver::iterator()) {
      callbacks.onConnectionError("Could not connect!");
    } else {
      callbacks.onConnected(std::move(*socket));
    }
  };

  auto resolveHandler = [socket, resolver, callbacks, connectHandler]
                        (const boost::system::error_code& errorCode, const tcp::resolver::iterator& it)
  {
    if (errorCode) {
      callbacks.onConnectionError("Could not resolve address: " + errorCode.message());
    } else {
      boost::asio::async_connect(*socket, it, tcp::resolver::iterator(), connectHandler);
    }
  };

  resolver->async_resolve(query, resolveHandler);
}
```

First of all, the `Callbacks` is just a struct with two callbacks: `onConnected(tcp::socket)` and `onConnectionError(const std::string&)`.

We'll create a `tcp::socket` and a `tcp::resolver` inside `shared_ptr` since they need to "survive" this whole procedure and can't be copied (atleast not `tcp::socket`. It can however be moved, but not using C++11 lambdas (?)).

Then we'll just create our two callbacks. `resolveHandler` needs to capture the socket, callbacks and connectHandler so that those "survive". It also needs to capture the actual resolver, otherwise I got an "Operation canceled"-error. The `connectHandler` just needs to capture the socket and the callbacks.

If the resolve is successful we'll call `async_connect` and tell it to try all endpoints. If the connection was successful we'll call our `onConnected`-callback using `std::move` and a reference to the socket. If it was not successful we'll call the `onConnectionError`-callback with an error message.

Does this looks sane? Are there any improvements I could make? Also, I'm wondering if the `std::move(*socket)` is safe? If I'm not mistaken, this will just move the socket to the `onConnected`-function call and leave the invalidated socket in the `shared_ptr` (which is deleted when the lambda returns). Or am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Looks good to me.
Given what is posted there is not much else to comment about.

- Object life-span: Looks good. (Though I recommend some unit-tests).
- Naming: Looks good.
- Style: Looks good. (Though personally I don't yet like '{' on the same line as other stuff).

The only thing I may have done differently (but this is very subjective and I would not expect you to change if you prefer your technique).

```
using namespace boost::asio::ip;

// I may have used
namespace BIP = boost::asio::ip;
```

Then prefixed all the boost stuff with `BIP::`. Just so I don't pollute the namespace.

But as I say your technique is totally valid since you have bound the scope of the using declaration to the function. If I was code reviewing within your company I may have commented but I would not block your merge to mainline over it.